# How to deal with popup messages selenium webdriver - Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am currently working on creating a script that will test the functionality of a website. Currently i'm blocked by a popup message that appears when certain conditions are met, when that popup message appears my script fails, if i add something like `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/button")).click();`
the script fails when the popup does not appear.
My question is: Is there a way to check "If the button exists then click button x if not move forward". I know after what action (click) the message appears/does not appear.
Keep in mind that i'm now learning java and selenium.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Banu

You are right, You should use if else condition.
Because you exactly know in which condition pop up appears and you can use pop up text in if condition.

By

```
driver.switchTo().alert().getText();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Alert class to handle Popups

Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.accept();

Answer (score -1):

You can use explicit wait for presence of button:-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10)
WebElement btn = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("---")));
```

Then to dismiss/accept the alert message use following code:-

```
 driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
 driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Comment: I tried to use the explicit wait, i get org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: No tab modal was open when attempting to get the dialog text
i was thinking about an IF method. if "A" no present then go to "B"

Comment: Banu, I am not sure about the navigation/nature of your application. I suggested explicit wait because you wanted to make sure whether a button is present or not and then wanted to click on the button. You might have got suggestion of add exception for the function, so add that if the case is.